# Problem when installing module with composer

Tags: magento2, error, composer

When I run the following command on my Magento 2.3.3 store I get an error:

`composer require fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2`

This is the error I'm getting:

```
    - magento/framework 100.1.15 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.14 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.13 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.12 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.11 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.10 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.9 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.8 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.6 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.5 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.4 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.3 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.2 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.1 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.0 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 101.0.0
    - magento/framework 101.0.1 requires composer/composer 1.4.1 -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.4.1].
    - magento/framework 101.0.2 requires composer/composer 1.4.1 -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.4.1].
    - magento/framework 101.0.3 requires composer/composer 1.4.1 -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.4.1].
    - magento/framework 101.0.4 requires composer/composer 1.4.1 -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.4.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install composer/composer 1.4.1|install magento/framework 101.0.0
    - Installation request for fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2 ^8.2 -> satisfiable by fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2[8.2.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 102.0.3|install magento/framework 101.0.0|install magento/framework 101.0.1|install magento/framework 101.0.2|install magento/framework 101.0.3|install magento/framework 101.0.4
    - Conclusion: remove magento/framework 102.0.3|install magento/framework 101.0.0|install magento/framework 101.0.1|install magento/framework 101.0.2|install magento/framework 101.0.3|install magento/framework 101.0.4
    - fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2 8.2.2 requires magento/framework 100.1.0 - 100.1.18 | 101.0.0 - 101.0.9 | 102.0.0 - 102.0.2 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 101.0.2, 100.1.12, 101.0.3, 100.1.13, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 100.1.14, 100.1.15, 101.0.6, 100.1.16, 101.0.7, 102.0.0, 100.1.17, 102.0.1, 101.0.8, 102.0.2, 100.1.18, 101.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 101.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 101.0.6].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.16].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 101.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 102.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.17].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 102.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 101.0.8].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 102.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.18].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 101.0.9].
    - Installation request for magento/framework (locked at 102.0.3) -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.3].
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I have modified my composer.lock file so it doesnt say anyting with magento/framwork below version 102.*

EDIT: 
When I enter the following command:

`composer require fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2 --ignore-platform-reqs`

I get the following error:

````
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 101.0.0
    - magento/framework 101.0.1 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.2 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.3 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.4 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.5 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.6 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.7 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.8 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - magento/framework 101.0.9 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.3.4 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.3.4].
    - Conclusion: don't install colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract v1.3.4|install magento/framework 101.0.0
    - Installation request for fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2 ^8.2 -> satisfiable by fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2[8.2.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 102.0.3|install magento/framework 101.0.0|install magento/framework 101.0.1|install magento/framework 101.0.2|install magento/framework 101.0.3|install magento/framework 101.0.4|install magento/framework 101.0.5|install magento/framework 101.0.6|install magento/framework 101.0.7|install magento/framework 101.0.8|install magento/framework 101.0.9
    - Conclusion: remove magento/framework 102.0.3|install magento/framework 101.0.0|install magento/framework 101.0.1|install magento/framework 101.0.2|install magento/framework 101.0.3|install magento/framework 101.0.4|install magento/framework 101.0.5|install magento/framework 101.0.6|install magento/framework 101.0.7|install magento/framework 101.0.8|install magento/framework 101.0.9
    - fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2 8.2.2 requires magento/framework 100.1.0 - 100.1.18 | 101.0.0 - 101.0.9 | 102.0.0 - 102.0.2 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 101.0.2, 100.1.12, 101.0.3, 100.1.13, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 100.1.14, 100.1.15, 101.0.6, 100.1.16, 101.0.7, 102.0.0, 100.1.17, 102.0.1, 101.0.8, 102.0.2, 100.1.18, 101.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.4].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.6].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.7].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.8].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.10].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.11].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.12].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.13].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.14].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.15].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.16].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 102.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.17].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 102.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 102.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 100.1.18].
    - Installation request for magento/framework (locked at 102.0.3) -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.3].```
````

Comment: why dont you try to contact the developers first? https://store.fooman.co.nz/media/custom/upload/InstallationInstructions-FoomanPdfCustomiserM2.pdf

Comment: try this composer require fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2  your require version --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: The first error report itself is pretty clear. It is specifying that the php version that is installed in your system is not acceptable by the module. So you have to downgrade your php version and install php7.0 Refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-different-upgrade-or-downgrade-php-version-in-still-supported) to do that.
Note : When downgrading the php version the method specified there may not work if you are using ubuntu 19.10. In that case run the following command:
```sudo update-alternatives --config php```.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I think your magento version is not compatible with the `fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2` version. Please check the change log https://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-pdf-customiser-m2.html.

Comment: I have magento version 2.3.3 and downloaded the 2.3.3 module

Comment: @Akif PHP 7.1.16-1

Comment: have you try to run composer update?

Comment: The composer update updates some packages, but when i do composer require fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2 it gives the same error as above.

Answer (score 1):

Please **run** below command from your SSH terminal:

```
composer require fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2:* --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: This doesnt work, see the EDIT: in my question

Comment: update your original composer.lock after run this command.

Answer (score 0):

This is PHP version issue please run below command to avoid version issue

```
composer require fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2 --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: Hi, i have updated the question with new info, when i enter your command it gives me another error

Comment: Which error getting?

Comment: I have updated my question below the EDIT: